# FreeBSD(Samba4)でファイルサーバを構築で、Windows側のパーミッションがおかしい

Tags: windows, samba

**構成**

> サーバーOS： FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE
>   Sambaのバージョン: 4.1.16
>   クライアント側: Windows7/8
>   ActiveDirectoryは構築していません

上記の構成で、sambaを用いてファイル共有を実装しております。  
Windows側からは、共有ディレクトリへ資格情報(FreeBSDのユーザー名/Password)で接続をしております。

**現象**

FreeBSDから見ると共有ディレクトリのファイルパーミッションが

```
-rwxrw---- demo member hoge.txt
```

Windowsから見ると共有ディレクトリのファイルパーミッション

```
-rwxr----- demo member hoge.txt
```

となり、Windowsからですと、他のmemberグループのユーザーが書き込みできません。
解決策をご存知の方、教えて下さい。

smb4.confの内容

```
[global]
    dos charset = CP932
    server string = Samba Server (FreeBSD@sv1)
    server role = standalone server
    log file = /var/log/samba4/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    server max protocol = SMB2
    unix extensions = No
    nsupdate command = /usr/local/bin/samba-nsupdate -g
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    create mask = 0660
    force create mode = 0660
    directory mask = 0770
    force directory mode = 0770
    map acl inherit = Yes

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    path = /home/%S
    read only = No
    create mask = 0640

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes
    print ok = Yes
    browseable = No

[commons]
    comment = commons
    path = /data/commons
    read only = No
    vfs objects = zfsacl
    nfs4:chown = yes
    nfs4:acedup = merge
    nfs4:mode = special
```

commonsが共有ディレクトリ名です。

**追記**

getfaclコマンドの結果です。

```
$ getfacl /data/commons
# file: /data/commons
# owner: root
# group: member
owner@:rwxp--aARWcCos:------:allow
group@:rwxp--a-R-c--s:------:allow
everyone@:------a-R-c--s:------:allow
```

Comment: [commons] に `inherit acls = yes` を追加するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: freebsdのタグを追加しました

Comment: 共有ディレクトリは ZFS上にあるのでしょうか。FreeBSD側から共有ディレクトリに対して `getfacl`(1) を実行した結果と、Windows側から `cacls.exe` を実行した結果も載せてください。